# Creating new vertices at the wireframe subdivision in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, computational-geometry, noise, topology

I understand that the [THREE.SubdivisionModifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44373754/apply-three-js-subdivision-modifier-without-changing-outer-geometry) will section a shape's wireframe, but as far as I understand this doesn't add any new vertices to the geometry. How can I add new vertices to the geometry representing the intersection points of the subdivisions? I'm trying to add noisy distortions to a convex hull, so I need to either add new vertices along the shapes'faces, bend each subdivision independently, or else copy the geometry into a new similar geometry with a higher "`resolution`" of vertices along its faces.

Is any one of those options supported by Three.js? Thanks!

Comment: You can add new vertices and the faces, Here is my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51172095/change-the-color-of-mesh-created-using-face3/51211300#51211300 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51170190/fill-area-between-lines-with-color-in-three-js/51211200#51211200

Comment: Please do let me know what have you tried so far?